# Where can I see the default styles.xml in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Where can I find the source code of the definition of the android default styles, such as `?android:attr/progressBarStyle`?

I know that the Android repo is replicated in https://github.com/android but... I just can't find the styles.xml, strings.xml, etc there!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the [value resources directory](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res/values).

Answer (score 3):

With the ADT plugin in Eclipse, you can just type `android.R.somegroup.someconstant`, then mouse-over and hold `CTRL` (doesn't even have to be syntactically correct/compilable for that) -- this will give you a popup with two (or in case of `strings.xml` more) options to "Open declaration in [some XML file]".

For reasons that escape me, this doesn't seem to work for any of `android.R.style.*` -- for everything else it does (`color`, `string`, `layout`, ...).